# How to set Headless Chrome wait until the page is fully loaded before printing?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, google-chrome-headless

The command to use headless Chrome to print webpage as PDF is `chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf https://www.chromestatus.com/`. The [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) has a feature `--window-status ready_to_print` to do so.

I ask this question because when I print this [webpage](http://www.randomservices.org/random/foundations/Functions.html) contains `MathJax.js`, it has an error as follows:

[image]

The page source of that webpage has the following lines related to `mathjax`

```
<script src="../scripts.js"></script>
<script src="../../MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_SVG"></script>
```

I would like to ask if there is an option so that Headless Chrome will wait until the page is fully loaded before printing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use two options to achieve this goal: `--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw` and `--virtual-time-budget=10000`.

Comment: What does `--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw` do?

Comment: both are need to work `--virtual-time-budget` without `--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw` doesn't seems to work very well.... for me, it's working when both are there

Comment: other usefull options `--hide-scrollbars` `--disable-translate` `--disable-gpu`

Comment: where can I find full list of parameters?

Comment: @Yuseferi An attempt at a full list of parameters is here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/master/docs/chrome-flags-for-tools.md